# alternate row in classes exculde display none in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of `li` in a `ul` to apply css class, I am using following code.

```
$('#' + firstContainer + ' li:nth-child(even)').addClass('AltRow');
$('#' + firstContainer + ' li:nth-child(odd)').removeClass('AltRow');
$('#' + secondContainer + ' li:nth-child(even)').addClass('AltRow');
$('#' + secondContainer + ' li:nth-child(odd)').removeClass('AltRow');
```

Now there are some `li` which are set to display none so I need to exculde those while applying class.

How to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe even shorter/cleaner:

```
$('#' + firstContainer + ' li, #' + secondContainer + ' li').removeClass('AltRow');
$('#' + firstContainer + ' li:visible:even').addClass('AltRow');
$('#' + secondContainer + ' li:visible:even').addClass('AltRow');
```

here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manuel/PyqFJ/)

Answer (score 2):

The below should work for you:

```
$('#' + firstContainer + ' li:visible').filter(":even").addClass("AltRow");
$('#' + firstContainer + ' li:visible').filter(":odd").removeClass("AltRow");
$('#' + secondContainer + ' li:visible').filter(":even").addClass("AltRow");
$('#' + secondContainer + ' li:visible').filter(":odd").removeClass("AltRow");
```

[**Here's a fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/HQeH7/1/)

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#' + firstContainer + ' li').removeClass('AltRow').is(':visible:even');
$('#' + secondContainer + ' li').removeClass('AltRow').is(':visible:even');
```

Edit: my bad I didn't read every single line of code

Comment: thanks for your answer but it didn't made any difference. the traversing logic is still counting it .

Comment: i think i am not able to make myself clear i will give you an example lets say i have 5 li in which 3rd one is set to display none.so 1 and 3rd li should not have the altrow class but after applying your code both 2nd and 3rd has that class since the 3rd li is set to display none.

Comment: i would recommand using `:visible` instead of `is(':visible')` see the performance: http://jsperf.com/visible-vs-is-visible

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#' + firstContainer + ' li:even:visible').addClass('AltRow');
$('#' + firstContainer + ' li:odd:visible').removeClass('AltRow');
$('#' + secondContainer + ' li:even:visible').addClass('AltRow');
$('#' + secondContainer + ' li:odd:visible').removeClass('AltRow');
```